# Non-trivial examples of $E[X|X^2] = X$ and $E[Y|Y^2] = 0$.

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

I want to find a few examples of non-trivial random variables $X, Y$ such that $E[X|X^2] = X$ and $E[Y|Y^2] = 0$.

From what i gather for $E[X|X^2] = X$ i need to find a function such that if $X=u$ then $f(-u)=0$. Then for $E[Y|Y^2] = 0$ if $Y=u$ then $f(u)=f(-u)$.

Comment: Any random variable $X$ with pdf $f_X(x) = 0$ for any $x < 0$ satisfies the first property, e.g. exponential, chi-squared, uniform on a positive interval. For $Y$, any distribution that is symmetric around $0$ works, e.g. normal, Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ is any positive random variable. Then $X=\sqrt{X^2}$ is $\sigma(X^2)$-measurable so the conditional expectation of $X$ given $X^2$ is $X$.

Let $Y$ be any $L^2$ symmetric random variable. Then, for any bounded function $g$, $Yg(Y^2)$ is symmetric so has mean $0$, which is the mean value of $0\cdot g(Y^2)$, and $0$ is $\sigma(Y^2)$-measurable, so the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $Y^2$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at

[A problem in Jun Shao mathematical statistics:exercises and solutions P33](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143549/a-problem-in-jun-shao-mathematical-statisticsexercises-and-solutions-p33/3153326#3153326)

**example of conditions that** $E(X|X^2)=0$

$E(X|X^2=t)=\sqrt(t) \bigg(\frac{f(\sqrt(t))-f(-\sqrt(t))}{f(\sqrt(t))+f(-\sqrt(t))} \bigg)$

$E(X|X^2=t)=0$ hence $f(\sqrt(t))-f(-\sqrt(t))=0$

so it is enough

$f(t)=f(-t)$  so you need to choose a symmetric distribution around Zero.

**example of conditions that** $E(X|X^2)=X$

$E(X|X^2=t)=\sqrt(t) $ if

$\bigg(\frac{f(\sqrt(t))-f(-\sqrt(t))}{f(\sqrt(t))+f(-\sqrt(t))} \bigg)=1$

so $2f(-\sqrt(t))=0$ so $X$ need to be positive.